# Modifying array via variable arguments

Tags: c, variadic-functions

I'm trying to modify an array via variable arguments by passing values of `va_arg` to the array but for some reason it gives weird results, Here is the code:

```c
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdarg.h>

void get_args(double* args, int argc, ...);

void get_args(double* args, int argc, ...) {
    va_list argv;
    va_start(argv, argc);

    if (argc == 1) {
        args[0] = va_arg(argv, double);
    }
    else if (argc == 4) {
        for (int i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
            args[i] = va_arg(argv, double);
        }
    }

    va_end(argv);
}

int main(void) {
    double args[4] = { 0, 0, 0, 0 };
    get_args(args, 4, 0, 1, 2, 3);

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
        printf("args[%d] = %f\n", i, args[i]);
    }
    
    return 0;
}
```

On Visual Studio (MSVC) it gives following:

```
args[0] = 0.000000
args[1] = 0.000000
args[2] = 0.000000
args[3] = -92559592143668871097826611732759620974286504571030640424648704.000000
```

On GCC it gives following:

```
args[0] = 0.000000
args[1] = 0.000000
args[2] = 0.000000
args[3] = 0.000000
```

Anyone knows what the mistake i done?

Comment: You do `va_arg(argv, double)`, but the actual type you passed is `int`. C-style variadic functions don't let you convert types like this, that's why `printf` has a bunch of format specifiers for different types.

Comment: `get_args(args, 4, 0., 1., 2., 3.);`

Comment: Try `get_args(args, 4, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);`. You are expecting `double` in `va_arg`, you must pass doubles.

Comment: Thanks so much! ♥
You really made my day after i wasted some time trying to figure out the problem...

Comment: Nitpick: everything shown is C, and may work in C++ but is not specific to it. The "C++" tag should be removed.

Comment: @Chris Removed the tag...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The types of the variadic arguments don't match the type given to `va_arg`.

The arguments you're passing to `get_args` i.e. `0, 1, 2, 3` are all of type `int`, but you're using type `double` when you try to retrieve them with `va_arg`.  This is a type mismatch which triggers [undefined behavior](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior).

Either pass arguments that have type `double`:

```
get_args(args, 4, 0.0, 1.0, 2.0, 3.0);
```

Or use `int` to pull the arguments off:

```
args[i] = va_arg(argv, int);
```